# Using directive for nested type definitions

Tags: c#, using-directives

I'm trying to use the `using` directive to define types in a functional manner to make code more readable. Let's say that my example.cs file looks like this:

```
using A = System.Tuple<int, int>;
using B = List<A>;
```

I get the error:

> CS0246 The type or namespace name 'A' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can I define nested types with `using` or is it not possible?

Comment: `using B = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Tuple<int, int>>;`. With using you can't use another using, always specify type name fully. You already experienced this when defining `A`, don't you? `using System;` can't fix the error.

Comment: @SzymonPajzert, I hope you don't mind, but I've added the error that's generated from your code snippet when I dropped it into a .cs file to replace your paraphrased version. I've done this so that the question is more easily findable by others in the future - If you're getting a different error (because I've mis-interpreted your question), please do roll the update back, or update it with the specific error you're getting =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C# Language Specification on learn.microsoft.com has a section that covers the [Using directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces#using-directives), specifically the type of using directive you're attempting to use is a "[Using alias directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces#using-alias-directives)":

> A using_alias_directive (Using alias directives) introduces an alias for a namespace or type.

The documentation highlights the permitted structure of a using_alias_directive as:

```
using_alias_directive
    : 'using' identifier '=' namespace_or_type_name ';'
    ;
```

Note that this only allows something which is a "namespace_or_type_name", but doesn't permit the use of another "using_alias_directive". One of the likely reasons for, this can be found part way through the documentation for them (emphasis mine):

> The order in which using_alias_directives are written has no significance, and resolution of the namespace_or_type_name referenced by a using_alias_directive is not affected by the using_alias_directive itself or by other using_directives in the immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body. **In other words, the namespace_or_type_name of a using_alias_directive is resolved as if the immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body had no using_directives**

In short, you cannot use an alias in another alias, I'm afraid.

Comment: All the authors of refactoring tools with an "organize/sort `using` directives" feature just breathed a sigh of relief.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, that's the understatement of the century! =)

Answer (score 0):

In C# 12 preview it is possible to [allow using alias directive to reference any kind of Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/using-alias-types).

> Beginning with C# 12, you can create aliases for types that were previously restricted, including tuple types, pointer types, and other unsafe types. For more information on the udpated rules.